# How to separate a long title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to separate a long title in ggplot2 by using

```
\n
```

like this:

```
ggtitle("text text \n text text")
```

And I receive two titles with big margin:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Is that the actual problem you're trying to solve? That a title is too long? Or are you trying to mimic the effect of having a title and a subtitle? Just asking to make sure the right solution is provided.

Comment: cannot reproduce the issue but does `theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=NULL))`  work?

Comment: Why don't you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @ Chris YEs!, Thanks!!!

Comment: @Chris, post as answer?

Comment: @BenBolker have done so now, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not reproduce the issue with the default ggplot theme, but it looks like the theme you are using has changed the `lineheight` of the plot title.

Your code should work with the addition of:

`theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=NULL))`